# Unable to print event without JSONstringify

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, javascript, events, web3j

I am trying to understand the difference among following cases while printing the event:
At web3.js

```
listenToEvent: function(){
    Contract.deployed().then(function(instance){
      instance.HelloWorld().watch(function(error, event){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(event);

        console.log(event); //1. It is not working
        console.log(event.args); // 2. It is giving all arguments 
        console.log(event.args.name); // 3. It is not working

      });
    });
  },
```

---

1. console.log(event); //1. It is not working
2. console.log(event.args); // 2. It is giving all arguments
3. console.log(event.args.name); // 3. It is not working; here name is the first argument in the event.

My question is If the object can't be print then why it is working for 2nd condition and if it is working then why it is failing for 3rd.

To access the arguments we can use this:
console.log(JSON.stringify(event.args.name));

While printing the event
console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
It gives the transaction details too, how to get that?

Appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Are you using web3 v1.0? You say it doesn't work what do you mean? Does it logs nothing or incorrect data?

Comment: web3 v0.2 and it doesn't showing any log.

Answer (score 0):

I also add issues using watch() on web3 to watch for events.

But I manage to solve them by using the alternative method ([docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events)):

```
// Or pass a callback to start watching immediately
var event = myContractInstance.MyEvent([{valueA: 23}] [, additionalFilterObject] , function(error, result){
  if (!error)
    console.log(result);
});
```

Try changing:

```
instance.HelloWorld().watch(function(error, event){
```

to

```
instance.HelloWorld({}, function(error, event){
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I am able to get the event log. I was asking what's the difference among those 3 cases which I mentioned.